What to do when the python library we want to use doesn't have a deb package？
We need to use some AI-related python libraries, most of which don't have deb packages, should we package them all into deb packages? Do you have any rules or suggestions from the community on this?
One of our current ideas is to include the whl packages of the Python library in our package and install them in a virtual environment in the postinst script of the package. This may not be prescriptive enough, and we wonder what the canonical approach in the community is for this.


One of our current ideas is to include the whl packages of the Python library in our package and install them in a virtual environment

That is exactly what the canonical approach is. Don't touch .deb packages at all; instead, create a virtual environment (with python3 -m venv), activate it, and use pip (python3 -m pip) to install the Python libraries you need into that virtual environment. Or you may want to use something like pipenv or pdm as a more convenient alternative to pip; the advantage of those tools is that they make it somewhat easier to manage the list of libraries that get installed.
If you have some special constraint you haven't mentioned here which means you really need these Python libraries to be installable using apt, then sure, instead of all that it might be reasonable to turn all the Python libraries into .deb packages. But it's quite rare that you actually need to do that; honestly, off the top of my head I can't think of any situation where it would be necessary.

At the moment we put the WHL files in our own deb package and install these WHL packages to the specified virtual environment via pip in the postinst script, which looks good?
If converting a WHL package to a deb package isn't necessary, that's great, because there are so many WHL packages involved that it would be a lot of work to convert them all to deb.

Well, what I'm suggesting is that you don't put the wheel files in a deb package at all - at least, you don't need to. If the wheels are on (or can be uploaded to) PyPI or some other package repository, you can just have pip fetch them directly from there. If not, you can just share a directory with all the wheel files, or a compressed archive (zip, tar.gz, etc.). Or, yes, you could put all the wheels in a deb package, which is basically a kind of compressed archive, but it probably gives you very little benefit compared to a plain old tar.gz file or some such thing.

It might be a good idea for us to have the wheel packages in one deb package. If we pull through pip, then we can't deploy the environment through the offline deb package, and it may not be good to perform operations that require the network in the postinst script of the deb package.
